# Subtract across Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array in the shape (244,244,3). Each holds a RGB image as numpy array. From each of the channels I want to subtract a value.

Of course I can easily do it with a for loop, but I assume that there is a faster way in numpy?

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Show us the loopy version?

Comment: Are you subtracting an array of values of the same size? In that case you can just do `array1 - array2`; as simple as that. If this is not the case, can you clarify the dimensions of the values you'd like to substract?

Comment: that shape suggests that it is rgb image.  your reference to 'each', does that mean you have others with the same shape?

Answer (score 5):

You may simply subtract a 3-vector, numpy will broadcast it automatically.

Little demo with a 5x5 RGB image, subtracting 2 from red channel, 5 from green channel, 3 from blue channel:

```
>>> A = 10*np.ones((5,5,3), dtype=int)
>>> A -= [2, 5, 3]
>>> A[:,:,0]  # Red
array([[8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]])
>>> A[:,:,1]  # Green
array([[5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]])
>>> A[:,:,2]  # Blue
array([[7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]])
```